# How can I create a listener for creating voice channels with discord.js?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I have been trying to create sort of a listener thing, where if a person joins a voice channel called "Join to Create", it creates another voice channel named "voice - " in a specific category, and then it moves them in the newly created voice channel, and I want the newly created channel to have a max of 3 members allowed to join, also once everyone has left the channel and the channel is completely empty it deletes it.

Thanks to anyone that helps in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's create a voice channel with user limit

```js
let FinalChannel; //Put this outside functions so that we can use it later
message.guild.channels.create('Voics-!!!', "voice").then(c => {
    c.setUserLimit("5");
    FinalChannel = c;
});
```

Then,

```js
client.on('voiceStateUpdate', (oldState, newState) => {
    if (oldState.member.user.bot) return; //Bot filter
    if(!newState.channelID) return; //left Channel
    if(newState.channelID !== "Join Voice Channel ID") return; //We don't care about other channels
    if(FinalChannel.members.cache.size < FinalChannel.userLimit){ //Check if there's more user than limit
        newState.member.setChannel(FinalChannel);
    }
})
```